# mySQL SELECT based on its result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
| id | parentID | columnName        |
|----|----------|-------------------|
| 1  | 2        | John              |
| 2  | 0        | Task name         |
| 3  | 4        | John              |
| 4  | 0        | Task another name |
```

I want to get John task, but also with its name so I'm wondering if it is any way to do it in single MySQL query?

```
SELECT id, parentID, person FROM table WHERE columnName = "John"
```

will result in user task, but I want to know how this task is named.

Comment: Could you give an example of the full output that you would like from the table that you gave as an example?

Comment: Unclear. Show desired result. PS. No `person` field in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a self-join:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    t.parentid, 
    t.columnname person,
    t1.columnname task
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.id = t.parentid
where t.person = 'John'
```

Comment: *t.person* Not found.

Comment: t.columnname would be person I guess

Comment: `where t.columnname = 'John'` makes that only John results are printed

Comment: @Akina: it looks like OP actually has an two distinct columns `columnName` and `person`...